# Sequencing of on do actions

Tags: control-m

I was wondering if there is any way to sequence what order the on do actions after a job occur. Currently I have on do actions for when the job ends not ok that seem to trigger after variable value actions even if they are higher on the list of on do actions. I am using version 9.0.21.000.

I have tried ordering the list of actions to have the variable value actions lower than the job ends not ok but the order of the list does not seem to change when they occur.

Answer (score 0):

I have never encountered them running out of sequence but have heard other users complain about this. What does the job log say, the output should reflect what you have in the post-processing panel.

Try exporting the job definition via XML, then confirm it looks to be in order in the XML output.

If still an issue, I would open a case with BMC. Are you using a standard OS?

Comment: I am using a standard OS but I found a work around to my problem. I was trying to have an on do action trigger when the job ends not ok and then perform another on do action based off variable value. I changed the job ends not ok action to OS completion status != 0 and it works in the correct order now. The jobs I am working with currently will have a completion status of >0 if they fail so it is not an issue currently. Not sure why this fixes things, I suspect something on BMCs side but I am not sure.

Comment: To get a definitive answer, I would open a case with BMC. In the help for older versions they had this comment against the "On Specific Statement" option -                   "If there is a match between the On statements and a statement set from the job’s log, the corresponding Do action statements are executed. Otherwise, Control‑M proceeds to the next statement set."